# Automatically add new source files to git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-luna

I'm on Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and am using the built in Git connectivity.

When I add a new source file, I'd like Eclipse to automatically add the new file to my set of pending changes. How can I do this? I've looked in Preferences > Team > Git, but see nothing.

This is a feature in IntelliJ IDEA. It prompts you when adding a file, and can be set to automatically add source files.

Comment: You want any new file present in your working tree to be automatically staged? Including generated files? Sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: @Jubobs I already have my .gitignore file set up to ignore generated files. So, yes, I do.

Comment: If you know what you're doing... :) Unfortunately, I only use Git from the command line, and I don't know how it's used in Eclipse.